# it statement inside loop iteration for each expect statement, mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have this array of objects.

```
let links = [
  { 
   url: 'some url 1',
   status: 200 
  },
  {
   url: 'some url 2',
   status: 200 
  }
]
```

Which is the result of calling LinkFunction asyncronously inside `before`:

```
  before(async () => {
    try {
      links = await LinkFunction();
    } catch (err) {
      assert.fail(err);
    }
  });
```

I would like to check if the `url` and `status` properties exist and if their types are correspondingly string and number.
Note: The specified object is just a sample of a big response. So the loop is required for iteration in any case.

I've done this iteration:

```
  it('Array to contain some props', () => {
    links.map(property => {
      expect(property).to.have.property('url').to.be.a('string');
      expect(property).to.have.property('status').to.be.a('number');
    });
  });
```

But I would like to have something like this:

```
it('Array to contain some props', () => {//or describe would be better here
  links.map(property => {
    it('link array to contain url string', () => {
      expect(property).to.have.property('url').to.be.a('string');
    });
    it('link array to contain status number', () => {
      expect(property).to.have.property('status').to.be.a('number');
    });
  });
});
```

Unfortunately `it` statements are ignored inside map. Maybe it's because of the several nested it statements. So How can I implement a similar logic?

**Update:**

[My full code:](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rRRmMw?editors=1010)

Comment: `it`s inside a map seem to work fine (at least in this playground I found online) https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XGOwMV - can you clarify what you mean by "ignored"?

Comment: Maybe it's because of the description that I actually have in my code. I'll update the code

Comment: Please see updated questions. It's because of nested `it` statements

Comment: @undefinedUser I updated my answer below based on your updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use `forEach` instead of `map`.

Also, ["Passing arrow functions (aka "lambdas") to Mocha is discouraged"](https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions) so you will probably want to change those to normal functions.

Having said that, it works fine if `links` is defined as `mocha` initially runs the test file and collects the individual `it` tests:

```js
const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('links', function() {
  let links = [
    { 
     url: 'some url 1',
     status: 200 
    },
    {
     url: 'some url 2',
     status: 200 
    }
  ]

  links.forEach(function(property) {
    it('link array to contain url string', function() {
      expect(property).to.have.property('url').to.be.a('string');
    });
    it('link array to contain status number', function() {
      expect(property).to.have.property('status').to.be.a('number');
    });
  });
});
```

..results in:

```js
> mocha



  links
    √ link array to contain url string
    √ link array to contain status number
    √ link array to contain url string
    √ link array to contain status number


  4 passing (14ms)
```

---

**Update**

As you have found, `it` only works at the top level or with a `describe`:

```js
before(function() {
  it('will NOT work here', function() { });
});

it('will work here', function() {
  it('will NOT work here', function() { });      
});
```

Also, `links` must be available while the test is first running and the `it` tests are being collected by `mocha` so this doesn't work either:

```js
describe('links', function() {

  let links = [];

  before(function() {
    links = [
      { 
       url: 'some url 1',
       status: 200 
      },
      {
       url: 'some url 2',
       status: 200 
      }
    ];
  });

  // This won't work...
  links.forEach(function(property) {
    // .. since links is still an empty array when this runs
    it('should...', function() { /* ... */ });
  });

});
```

From your question update it looks like your code retrieves `links` from an `async` function call in `before`.  Because of this, there is no way to have `links` populated at the time the test is first running and the `it` tests are collected.

So it looks like you won't be able to map across the items in `links` to create your `it` tests, and will instead need to take the approach you described by mapping across the items in `links` within a single test.